# sending data rows to combo box

Tags: php, html, mysql

First of all this one its just a part of my code, what I'm trying to do here is to send data from DB to html input by clicking a button, other text-input is doing good but in my `combo-box` I got the problem of not showing anything, I tried to use the same way of other input(add the echo inside the value) its not working on with me, any ideas ??

The code is working without any ERROR

```
<?php
    $query10s = "select payement.ID_PAYEMENT,DATE_PAYEMENT,TYPE_DE_PAYEMENT,PRIX,MOIS_PAYEMENT  from eleve,payement,payer where eleve.CIN_ELEVE = payer.CIN_ELEVE and payement.ID_PAYEMENT = payer.ID_PAYEMENT and eleve.CIN_ELEVE = '$InputCIN'   group by payement.ID_PAYEMENT";
    $resultAf10 = mysqli_query($con,$query10s);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultAf10)>=0){
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultAf10)){          
            $ID_PAYEMENT = $rows['ID_PAYEMENT'];
            $DATE_PAYEMENT = $rows['DATE_PAYEMENT'];
            $TYPE_DE_PAYEMENT = $rows['TYPE_DE_PAYEMENT'];
            $PRIX = $rows['PRIX'];                         
            $MOIS_PAYEMENT = $rows['MOIS_PAYEMENT'];
        }
    } 

    ID PAYEMENT<input type='text' name='ID_PAYEMENT' class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($ID_PAYEMENT)){echo $ID_PAYEMENT;}?>">
    <div style="font-size:9px;display:none;" class="col-md-12 showAj1">
        DATE PAYEMENT<input type='text' name='DATE_PAYEMENT' class="form-control date" value="<?php if(isset($DATE_PAYEMENT)){echo $DATE_PAYEMENT;}?>">
        TYPE DE PAYEMENT<br>
        <select class='form-control' style="font-size:11px;" name="TYPE_DE_PAYEMENT" value="<?php if(isset($TYPE_DE_PAYEMENT)){echo $TYPE_DE_PAYEMENT;}?>">
            <option>Mentuel</option>
            <option>Frais inscription</option>
            <option>Droit examen</option>
        </select>
        PRIX<input type='text' name='PRIX' class="form-control col-md-12"  value="<?php if(isset($PRIX)){echo $PRIX;}?>"><span style="margin-left:280px;margin-top:-22px;position:absolute;font-size:10px;">DH</span>
        MOIS_PAYEMENT<select class="form-control" style="font-size:11px;" name="MOIS_PAYEMENT" value="<?php if(isset($MOIS_PAYEMENT)){echo $MOIS_PAYEMENT;}?>">
            <option>Janvier</option> 
            <option>Février </option>
            <option>Mars</option> 
            <option>Avril </option>
            <option>Mai </option>
            <option>Juin</option> 
            <option>Juillet </option>
            <option>Août </option>
            <option>Septembre </option>
            <option>Octobre </option>
            <option>Novembre</option> 
            <option>Décembre</option>
        </select><br>
 ?>
```

Comment: what happens if you `var_dump($rows)` immediately inside your `while($rows...)` statement?

Comment: @Sablefoste no result in any input !

Comment: That would indicate `mysqli_num_rows($resultAf10)>=0` is false; that is, you have no results.  Try running your query directly in MySQL, or in a tool such as phpMyAdmin and see the number of results.